# Strange leak from toilet refill valve

Tags: plumbing, water, toilet, valve

It's been now some weeks that my wc is behaving strange, leaking water when refilling. I found the time today to open it and I noticed that, after discharging, the refill mechanism seems to work fine but the water does not come out from where I expect it. I'll add some pics and explain.

[image]

on the left there is the valve, a fluidmaster 747 (pretty cheap standard piece it seems). Basically, when it refills water drips out from the top part, not where a hose is supposed to be attached (missing here, who know why, it has not fallen inside) but from the back, in a jet that sometimes is able to drip outside of the cover and makes the area below permanently wet. Sorry for gif quality but weight limit on images gave me trouble.

[image]

I'm not sure if this is the normal operation and it is just oriented wrong or what else happened here, how can I fix it so that water does not drip outside? It is cheap, but I would like to avoid replacement, also just so you know, I'm a tenant if it is relevant for any advice.

Comment: +1 for a GIF.  - 1 For strange, other planet, toilet water supply line.

Comment: Feel free to edit or suggest an edit, first post here so I'm open to any suggestion :) And thanks to  @Machavity for fixing the tags.

Comment: I have not seen one quite like that but would guess it is similar to others I have worked on , turn the water off push down on the float to bleed the water pressure and open that cap put a cup over the cap area, turn the water on (trying to flush rust and scale out) turn water off only takes a second or 2 to flush. Put the cap back on and verify it is working. Note the plastic may be brittle and crack or be cracked so be prepared to get a new valve (usually only 10-15$). If it doesn’t work a new valve may be needed , I usually have a spare fill valve and wax seal in my shop just in case.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In the end, I confirmed that that is not the normal way of working by checking the other bathroom (the thought of having one only occurred to me some weeks later, as I don't usually use it).

In that one, a cloth had been strapped on the top of the valve, so that water that would come out from there would not be able to go far but would stay inside, so I assumed the same problem had arisen and they solved it that way.

I thought of using the same trick, but I didn't because it would create a place for mold to grow and I wanted to avoid that. Instead I added a rectangular piece of plastic in the foam in the back so that the jet cannot reach the cover, and cannot go outside.

Comment: Thanks for coming back to post your solution! Please be sure to give yourself a check-mark so others know this has been solved. Also, I'd suggest getting the landlord in on the issue - show him what's you've done as a temporary fix to prevent flooding and water damage and have him to a proper, long-term fix.